# Connect to ESP8266 Ap itself

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I tried to set up ESP8266 as WIFI_AP_STA mode and wanted to get RSSI of the SSID which is broadcasted by ESP8266 AP itself. But it does not show its own SSID but it is visible to other devices.

The task I am trying to do is sensing object movement using WiFi signal strength, it can be done by two ESP8266 modules but I want to test it with its own AP and client.

Help!

Comment: How do you plan to sense object movement with just one ESP? I'd guess that sensing movement is done by checking if the RSSI gets lower; if it does, the physical distance between the two ESPs probably got bigger. Then, the single ESP solution wouldn't work anyway. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the typical design of wireless transceiver to not sense the signal that is sent by itself.
There's only one transceiver on an ESP8266, so it is not possible to connect to itself.